# Error occurred "unhandled signal 11, terminating" in executing code with PIGPIO

Tags: raspbian, serial, uart, gps, pigpio

I would like to connect GPS Module by using PIGPIO.
but I can't.
My code that I show below gets "Segment Violation", but I have no idea.

Here is GPS spec.

> GPS Receiver chip->MT3339
>
> receiver frequency->1575.42MHz
>
> receiver channel numbers->66(Acquisition) 22(tracking)
>
> Satellite System->GPS(America), QZSS(Japan)
>
> tracking sensitivity->-164dBm(typ.)
>
> output data format->NMEA0183 V3.01
>
> I/O Signal level->CMOS logic (3.3V), asynchronous serial signal
>
> UART  signaling rate->9600bps(default), from 4800 to 115200bps
>
> Output data update rate-> once in second, from 1 to 10 in second
>
> geodetic reference system->WGS1984
>
> data bit-> 8bit / non parity, stop bit : 1 bit
>
> flow control->none

[image: GPIOs in use]

[image: GPS]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
 
#define TXD 29 //  5
#define RXD 11 //  17


int main(){
//  gpioTerminate();
char *buf;
int gsr = 0;
int count = 0;
gpioPulse_t pulse[2];
pulse[0].gpioOn = (1<<RXD);
pulse[0].gpioOff = 0;
pulse[0].usDelay = 10;

pulse[1].gpioOn = 0;
pulse[1].gpioOff = (1<<RXD);
pulse[1].usDelay = 10;

buf = malloc(100);

int wave_id;

if(buf == NULL) /* no memory */ exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 
if (gpioInitialise() < 0){
    // pigpio initialisation failed.
    fprintf(stderr, "PIGPIO INITIALISATION FAILED\n");
    return 1;
}

gpioWaveClear();


gpioSetMode(TXD, PI_INPUT);
 
gpioSetMode(RXD, PI_OUTPUT);

gpioSerialReadOpen(TXD, 9600, 8);

gpioWaveAddNew();

gpioWaveAddGeneric(2, pulse);

wave_id = gpioWaveCreate();

char* errstr;

sprintf(errstr, "%d", wave_id);

strcat(errstr, ":PIGPIO WAVE WASN'T ESTABLISHED\n");

if(wave_id < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, errstr);
    return 1;
}

// pigpio initialised okey.

gpioWaveTxSend(wave_id, PI_WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT); 
 
 
gpioSerialReadOpen(TXD, 9600, 8);
 
while(count < 5000){
    gsr = gpioSerialRead(TXD, buf, 8);
    if(gsr < 0)
    {
         printf("%d\n", gsr);
    }else{
        fwrite(buf, 8, 1, stdout);
    }
    sleep(100);
    count++;
}
 
gpioWaveTxStop();

gpioSerialReadClose(TXD);

gpioWaveTxStop();
     
    // release memory
    gpioTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As usuall newbibeibeiebiebeib.. YOU NEED MORE POWER! Please read about good power supply and invest some smaller amount of bucks to buy a good one! Then try again. Also , donut power the module from Pi GPIO.. power it from power adapter. Its newbie mistake number 2

Comment: Thanks Willy, So, you mean there are wrong wiring?, or should I have more current of electricity?  I saw Arduino operate normally this module by softserial before.

Comment: PSU issues are common, but extremely unlikely to give you a Segment Violation that the OP is getting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points.

1. The crash is caused by attempting to write to unassigned memory. You
   declare errstr as a pointer to memory but don't point it anywhere
   and don't allocate any memory for where you would point it.  Perhaps
   you intended to add a line errstr = malloc(100);
2. You read up to 8 bytes using gpioSerialRead().  You need to check
   the return status which will be either <0 for error, 0 for no data
   available (the normal case), or >0 for data available.  It is a
   non-blocking read, it will not wait for data to arrive.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define TXD 5 // GPS's TXD to RPI's RX
#define RXD 17 //  RPI's TX to GPS's RXD

int main()
{
   char buf[128], errstr[128];
   gpioPulse_t pulse[2];
   int wave_id, count;

   pulse[0].gpioOn = (1<<RXD);
   pulse[0].gpioOff = 0;
   pulse[0].usDelay = 10;

   pulse[1].gpioOn = 0;
   pulse[1].gpioOff = (1<<RXD);
   pulse[1].usDelay = 10;

   if (gpioInitialise() < 0)
   {
      // pigpio initialisation failed.
      fprintf(stderr, "PIGPIO INITIALISATION FAILED\n");
      return 1;
   }

   gpioWaveClear();

   gpioSetMode(TXD, PI_INPUT);

   gpioSetMode(RXD, PI_OUTPUT);

   gpioSerialReadOpen(TXD, 9600, 8);

   gpioWaveAddGeneric(2, pulse);

   wave_id = gpioWaveCreate();

   sprintf(errstr, "%d", wave_id);

   strcat(errstr, ":PIGPIO WAVE WASN'T ESTABLISHED\n");

   if (wave_id < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, errstr);
      return 1;
   }

  // pigpio initialised okey.

   gpioWaveTxSend(wave_id, PI_WAVE_MODE_ONE_SHOT); 

   while(1)
   {
      count = gpioSerialRead(TXD, buf, sizeof(buf)-1);
      if (count > 0)
      {
         buf[count] = 0;
         printf("c=%d %s\n", count, buf);
      }
      sleep(1);
   }

   gpioWaveTxStop();

   gpioSerialReadClose(TXD);

   gpioWaveTxStop();

   // release memory
   gpioTerminate();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I modified the code,but the same error issue occured, There is a long way to go.By the way Thanks.

Comment: @NEWBIEEBIEE I added the modified code.

Comment: @ joan ,Thank you for giving me a hand.That's it,finally I can take some message  like "43455.807,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*44
$GPGLL,,,,,043455.807,V,N*76
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
" Thank you so much.

Comment: I appreciate that you trim this code. beautiful.